# Need to put HTML within the error label container of jQuery Validate plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a simple validation for my input elements:

```
$("#forma").validate({
    errorClass: "red"
});
$("#input").each(function(index, elem) {
    var rules = {
        required:true
    };
    $(elem).rules("add", rules);
});
```

So, when error occurs - error messages are displayed and those error messages are inside label elements. For example, if you forget to enter the last name and you click submit button - this label element will be added:

```
<label id="lastname-error" class="red" for="lastname">This field is required.</label>
```

Now, I would like to add empty `span` element inside of those labels, at the beginning (prependTo) with the background-image and other CSS properties, so it will look like this:

```
<label id="lastname-error" class="red" for="lastname"><span class="myspan"></span><This field is required.</label>
```

I guess that this can be done by some event, like: when an error occurs - execute this:

```
var html = "<span></span>";
$(html).css({
    "background-image": "url('../images/arrowRight.png')",
    "padding-right": "26px",
    "background-repeat: no-repeat"
}).prependTo("label.red");
```

Do you know how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Desired output:

```
<label id="lastname-error" class="red" for="lastname"><span class="myspan"></span><This field is required.</label>
```

> "I guess that this can be done by some event"

No, you would not need to use a custom event or function.  You would simply use [the plugin's `errorPlacement` option](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#errorplacement) to construct your custom HTML.

The default code is `error.insertAfter(element)`, so this just needs to be modified.  You take the text of the error message and prepend it with your `<span>`, then replace the content of the default error label with your new HTML.

```
$("#forma").validate({
    // your rules & options,
    errorClass: "red",
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        var html = '<span class="myspan"></span>' + $(error).text();
        $(error).html(html).insertAfter(element);
    }
});
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/zrekogqd/**

Inspecting the DOM of the jsFiddle shows this result...

```
<label id="lastname-error" class="red" for="lastname">
    <span class="myspan"></span>This field is required.
</label>
```

Comment: That is a solution, thank you. I have just one more question relating to this - is there any event that is related to occurrence of errors (in the case of validation), so that I could use it like this: when an error occurrs - do something?

Comment: @PeraMika, please refer to [the complete page of options for this plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/). Also look at `invalidHandler` when button is clicked or `highlight` and `unhighlight` that fires on all invalid/valid events.   Obviously, `errorPlacement` fires on an error too.  The answer depends on what you're trying to do.  Otherwise, please "accept" this answer since it specifically solved your original question.  Thanks.